# Sorting apache solr results on the basis of information in query field ids

Tags: sorting, solr

I am finding it difficult to sort the Solr results on the basis of a field value.

Let's suppose I have 10 search results for a query string `'test'`.

Each result returns some detail values which also includes `pId` containing integer values.

I want that the results with `pId=3`, `pId=4` and `pId=10` should be sorted in the user defined order such as `(10, 3, 4)`, which means that:

1. result with `pId=10`
2. result with `pId=3`
3. result with `pId=4`

This order is neither `asc` nor `desc`. This is a user defined order.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2011/05/custom-sorting-in-solr-using-external.html) for custom sort in solr. Happy coding

Comment: My problem is different from your post. I don't need any external field sorting. My problem is regarding sorting within a internal field but it should not be asc or desc, it should be a customised order like if I define the order of id 10,3,2,4 then the records with id should come in this order.

Comment: Then the way sorting should be done shold be generalized. What is the logic for your sorting. Once we have the algorithm finalized, you can use [this](http://java.dzone.com/news/sorting-function-value-solr), to sort using the function.